# .NET CORE incorrect controller routing

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a problem with controller actions not returning views. They are looking in the wrong area.

I'm new to core but I've tried to read up online for material and I'm seeing a lot of Global.asax.cs, App_Start files etc that I'm not seeing in my created project.

My problem is:

**I created a project, implemented Areas like so:**

[image: File Structure]

**As an example, in CommonController *(which has 'Area("Common") area annotation)* I have a return view method**

```
        public ActionResult RoadMap()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**With the actionlink of:**

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Roadmap", "RoadMap", "Common")</span>
```

**But when I access the link, it tries to look in** "https://localhost:44325/Home/Common/RoadMap"

**My startup code contains:**

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "Account",
                  pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "Common",
                  pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Common}/{action}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "Email",
                  pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Email}/{action}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{area=Home}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

**I've tried looking for resources online but I'm at a loss with moving forwards.**

Comment: What is the goal you are looking for to achieve. Can you mention that clearly in your question?

Comment: Hi @VidiyaPrasanthPappannan, yes sorry I've added it now - "I have a problem with controller actions not returning views. They are looking in the wrong area."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the action link here. Since you did not mention Area, the default route of Home was selected.

The Actionlink format should be as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName" }, new{})
```

In you case it should be :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Roadmap", "RoadMap", "Common", new {Area = "Common"}, new{})
```

Official Microsoft Documentation :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thankyou @Vidiya! I'm very new to areas so this has enlightened me alot! Life saver :D